# Multiple Thread Writer with Single Thread Reader using PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Multiple Writer Threads with Single Reader Thread model.
The `ThreadMultipleDateReceiver` class is designed to read from multiple Threads.

```
public class ThreadMultipleDateReceiver extends Thread {

  private static final int MAX_CLIENT_THREADS = 4;
  private byte[] incomingBytes;
  private volatile boolean isRunning;
  private volatile List<ThreadStreamDateWriter> lThrdDate;

  private static PipedInputStream pipedInputStream;

  public ThreadMultipleDateReceiver() {
    lThrdDate = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(MAX_CLIENT_THREADS));
    pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
    System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Created");
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
      if (!lThrdDate.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver has:" + lThrdDate.size());
        for (int i = lThrdDate.size(); i > 0; i--) {
          if (lThrdDate.get(i - 1).getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
            lThrdDate.remove(i - 1);
          } else {
            System.out.println("I ThreadMultipleDateReceiver have:" + lThrdDate.get(i - 1).getNameDateWriter());
          }
        }
        incomingBytes = new byte[1024];
        try {
          String str = "";
          int iRd;
          System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver waiting:" + str);
          while ((iRd = pipedInputStream.read(incomingBytes)) != -1) {
            if (iRd > 0) {
              str += new String(incomingBytes);
            }
          }
          System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Received:\n\t:" + str);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
      } else {
        System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty");
      }
    }
    emptyDateWriters();
  }

  public void addDateWriter(ThreadStreamDateWriter threadDateWriter) {
    if (lThrdDate.size() < MAX_CLIENT_THREADS) {
      lThrdDate.add(threadDateWriter);
    }
  }

  private void emptyDateWriters() {
    if (!lThrdDate.isEmpty()) {
      for (int i = lThrdDate.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        ThreadStreamDateWriter threadDateWriter = lThrdDate.get(i - 1);
        threadDateWriter.stopThread();
        lThrdDate.remove(i - 1);
      }
    }
  }

  public PipedInputStream getPipedInputStream() {
    return pipedInputStream;
  }

  public void stopThread() {
    isRunning = false;
  }

}
```

And the single Writer Thread

```
public class ThreadStreamDateWriter extends Thread {
  String Self;
  private byte[] outgoingBytes;
  private volatile boolean isRunning;
  private static PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream;

  ThreadStreamDateWriter(String name, PipedInputStream snk) {
    Self = name;
    pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
    try {
      pipedOutputStream.connect(snk);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
      try {
        outgoingBytes = getInfo().getBytes();
        System.out.println("ThreadStreamDateWriter -> write to pipedOutputStream:" + new String(outgoingBytes));
        pipedOutputStream.write(outgoingBytes);
        System.out.println("ThreadStreamDateWriter -> wrote:" + new String(outgoingBytes));
        try { Thread.sleep(4000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
      } catch (IOException | NegativeArraySizeException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        isRunning = false;
      }
    }
  }

  String getInfo() {
      String sDtTm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
      return Self + " -> " + sDtTm;
  }

  public void stopThread() {
    isRunning = false;
  }

  public String getNameDateWriter() {
    return Self;
  }
}
```

How launch (I'm using Netbeans)?

```
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver thrdMDateReceiver = null;
ThreadStreamDateWriter thrdSDateWriter0 = null;
ThreadStreamDateWriter thrdSDateWriter1 = null;
  private void jtbDateExchangerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    if (jtbDateExchanger.isSelected()) {
      if (thrdMDateReceiver == null) {
        thrdMDateReceiver = new ThreadMultipleDateReceiver();
        thrdMDateReceiver.start();
      }
      if (thrdSDateWriter0 == null) {
        thrdSDateWriter0 = new ThreadStreamDateWriter("-0-", thrdMDateReceiver.getPipedInputStream());
        thrdSDateWriter0.start();
        thrdMDateReceiver.addDateWriter(thrdSDateWriter0);
      }
      if (thrdSDateWriter1 == null) {
        thrdSDateWriter1 = new ThreadStreamDateWriter("-1-", thrdMDateReceiver.getPipedInputStream());
        thrdSDateWriter1.start();
        thrdMDateReceiver.addDateWriter(thrdSDateWriter1);
      }
    } else {
      if (thrdMDateReceiver != null) {
        thrdMDateReceiver.stopThread();
      }
    }
  }
```

The **OUTPUT**

```
    run:
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Created
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty
.....
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver has:1
I ThreadMultipleDateReceiver have:-0-
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver waiting:
ThreadStreamDateWriter -> write to pipedOutputStream:-0- -> 20170608-090003
ThreadStreamDateWriter -> write to pipedOutputStream:-1- -> 20170608-090003
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 3 seconds)
```

The ThreadMultipleDateReceiver is blocked, and is not printing:

```
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Received:
    -1- -> 20170608-090003
```

or

```
ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Received:
    -0- -> 20170608-090003
```

**How solve it?**

Answer (score 0):

looks like your piped output stream is static, so every time you construct a ThreadStreamDateWriter, you are stepping on the old value of piped output stream.

try making this an instance variable and pass it into the constructor. so you only have one of them.

edit 1: i made the pipes instance variables and added some printouts. seems to be running longer now (see below):

edit 2: you second pipedOutputStream.connect(snk); is throwing. you can only connect one thing at a time.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
public class So44438086 {
    public static class ThreadMultipleDateReceiver extends Thread {
        private static final int MAX_CLIENT_THREADS=4;
        private byte[] incomingBytes;
        private volatile boolean isRunning;
        private volatile List<ThreadStreamDateWriter> lThrdDate;
        private /*static*/ PipedInputStream pipedInputStream;
        public ThreadMultipleDateReceiver() {
            lThrdDate=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(MAX_CLIENT_THREADS));
            pipedInputStream=new PipedInputStream();
            System.out.println("ctor setting pipedInputStream to: "+pipedInputStream);
            System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Created");
        }
        @Override public void run() {
            isRunning=true;
            while(isRunning) {
                if(!lThrdDate.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver has:"+lThrdDate.size());
                    for(int i=lThrdDate.size();i>0;i--) {
                        if(lThrdDate.get(i-1).getState()==Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
                            lThrdDate.remove(i-1);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("I ThreadMultipleDateReceiver have:"+lThrdDate.get(i-1).getNameDateWriter());
                        }
                    }
                    incomingBytes=new byte[1024];
                    try {
                        String str="";
                        int iRd;
                        System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver waiting:"+str);
                        System.out.println("reading: "+pipedInputStream);
                        while((iRd=pipedInputStream.read(incomingBytes))!=-1) {
                            if(iRd>0) {
                                str+=new String(incomingBytes);
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Received:\n\t:"+str);
                    } catch(IOException e) {}
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ThreadMultipleDateReceiver Empty");
                }
            }
            emptyDateWriters();
        }
        public void addDateWriter(ThreadStreamDateWriter threadDateWriter) {
            if(lThrdDate.size()<MAX_CLIENT_THREADS) {
                lThrdDate.add(threadDateWriter);
            }
        }
        private void emptyDateWriters() {
            if(!lThrdDate.isEmpty()) {
                for(int i=lThrdDate.size();i>0;i--) {
                    ThreadStreamDateWriter threadDateWriter=lThrdDate.get(i-1);
                    threadDateWriter.stopThread();
                    lThrdDate.remove(i-1);
                }
            }
        }
        public PipedInputStream getPipedInputStream() {
            return pipedInputStream;
        }
        public void stopThread() {
            isRunning=false;
        }
    }
    public static class ThreadStreamDateWriter extends Thread {
        String Self;
        private byte[] outgoingBytes;
        private volatile boolean isRunning;
        private /*static*/ PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream;
        ThreadStreamDateWriter(String name,PipedInputStream snk) {
            Self=name;
            pipedOutputStream=new PipedOutputStream();
            System.out.println("ctor setting pipedOutputStream to: "+pipedOutputStream);
            try {
                pipedOutputStream.connect(snk);
                System.out.println(pipedOutputStream+" connectd to: "+snk);
            } catch(IOException e) {}
        }
        @Override public void run() {
            isRunning=true;
            while(isRunning) {
                try {
                    outgoingBytes=getInfo().getBytes();
                    System.out.println("ThreadStreamDateWriter -> write to pipedOutputStream:"+new String(outgoingBytes));
                    System.out.println("writing to: "+pipedOutputStream);
                    pipedOutputStream.write(outgoingBytes);
                    System.out.println("ThreadStreamDateWriter -> wrote:"+new String(outgoingBytes));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
                } catch(IOException|NegativeArraySizeException|IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    isRunning=false;
                }
            }
        }
        String getInfo() {
            String sDtTm=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            return Self+" -> "+sDtTm;
        }
        public void stopThread() {
            isRunning=false;
        }
        public String getNameDateWriter() {
            return Self;
        }
    }
    private void foo() {
        if(thrdMDateReceiver==null) {
            thrdMDateReceiver=new ThreadMultipleDateReceiver();
            thrdMDateReceiver.start();
        }
        if(thrdSDateWriter0==null) {
            thrdSDateWriter0=new ThreadStreamDateWriter("-0-",thrdMDateReceiver.getPipedInputStream());
            thrdSDateWriter0.start();
            thrdMDateReceiver.addDateWriter(thrdSDateWriter0);
        }
        if(thrdSDateWriter1==null) {
            thrdSDateWriter1=new ThreadStreamDateWriter("-1-",thrdMDateReceiver.getPipedInputStream());
            thrdSDateWriter1.start();
            thrdMDateReceiver.addDateWriter(thrdSDateWriter1);
        }
    }
    void run() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(("running"));
        foo();
        System.out.println(("sleeping"));
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(("stopping"));
        if(thrdMDateReceiver!=null) {
            thrdMDateReceiver.stopThread();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new So44438086().run();
    }
    ThreadMultipleDateReceiver thrdMDateReceiver=null;
    ThreadStreamDateWriter thrdSDateWriter0=null;
    ThreadStreamDateWriter thrdSDateWriter1=null;
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use only One PipedOutpudStream for multiple PipedInpudStream?

Comment: you can use one, but you are making 3 and stepping on the first 2 if i am reading your code correctly. so your stuff may be going to 3 different pipes.

Comment: I know its object conceptual mistake... Maybe the PipedXxxputStream it's not the apropiated object, But I need Multiple Writer Objects One Reader Object. I want to avoid the Blocking...

Comment: you could have multiple threads putting things into a queue. and one thread reading things from the queue.

Comment: try something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/ and see where the time is going.

Comment: At Last! I can test your proposed code. But I wan't that ThreadStreamDateWriter works simultaneosly, Only I have "prints" of ThreadStreamDateWriter -> write to pipedOutputStream:-0- ->, But 1 not... HAve you some alternative?